# why prototype inheritance is efficient and consume less memory than closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, prototypal-inheritance

I have searched the internet but was not able to understand this question answer. Many people have different answer to the same question. I'm kinda confused.

Why prefer prototype inheritance over a closure, and why does it consume less memory than a closure?

I have written two examples down below, so that you have basic idea of what I'm asking.

```
var foo = function () {
    this.bar = function () {
        // do something
    };
};
```

and the other one is:

```
var foo = function () { };
foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    // do something
};
```

Comment: Prototypes allow all `foo`s to share the same function instance, and are compatible with `class`.

Comment: What about closure?

Comment: They don’t and aren’t.

Comment: Can you write down a brief answer?

Comment: @Ry- Closures also share the same function, they just have different environments, which are analogous to the objects in prototype inheritance.

Comment: @Barmar: `new foo().bar !== new foo().bar` ≠ “share the same function instance”

Comment: @Ry- That isn't comparing the functions, it's comparing the closures. The two closures contain the same underlying function.

Comment: @Barmar: What point are you trying to make?

Comment: That the two closures share the same function bodies inside the different closures. Try `x = new foo(); y = new foo(); console.dir(x.bar); console.dir(y.bar);` Then look at the `[[FunctionLocation]]` properties, they should be the same.

Comment: @Barmar: Okay, but that doesn’t make them the same function instance, which is what I said…

Comment: @Ry- We must be using different interpretations of "same function instance". A closure is a function + environment. They're the same function with different environments.

Comment: @Barmar: I’m referring to the concepts of “function”, “instance”, and “same” within JavaScript.

Comment: @Ry- So what is the Javascript term for what I'm talking about? The problem is that the Javascript `Function` class is actually a closure, the underlying object that contains the code doesn't seem to have a name, since it's not accessible.

Comment: In mdn Docs, i have read this line "prototype chain provides a very powerful although potentially dangerous mechanism to override or extend object behavior." What docs are referring too?
@Barmar

Comment: They're talking about the flexibility that I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects with associated functions and closures are in some ways isomorphic. [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html), a classic CS textbook, uses closures to implement an object-oriented programming design (it uses Scheme, but the concepts are similar).

However, in JavaScript, objects are built into the language, and they're implemented very efficiently. And prototypes are managed automatically -- you can implement subclasses by chaining prototypes, and the JavaScript engine automatically searches through the prototype chain to find the appropriate method. This is harder to accomplish just using closures, because getting all the variable scopes right is difficult. When using prototypes, the special `this` object contains the original object, and this allows you to get at all its properties.

Objects with prototypes are also more flexible, because you can assign a whole prototype to a new object's prototype. If you then modify the prototype, it affects all the other objects that reference it.

Answer (score 0):

The advantages of using the prototype approach is speed and a low memory usage.

The disadvantage is that private variables and functions cannot be shared between public methods since there’s no way to create a common closure.